# HiDPI support with java 9+, scalling issue with JTable gridlines with Windows L&F - but not Nimbus

Tags: java, look-and-feel, nimbus, hidpi

I'm migrating my Swing app to Java 11 to take advantage of the HiDPI display support. I'm using a Samsung monitor with resolution set to 3840x2160, scaling at 125%, with Windows 10.

Although java 9 and above are advertised as properly handling HiDPI scaling, when displaying a simple JTable, the gridlines appear of different thickness, as shown here:

[image: JTable gridlines issue]

Here's the code for this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        JTable table = new JTable(12,6);

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setShowGrid(true);
        table.setRowHeight(25);

        dialog.setContentPane(sp);
        dialog.setSize(300,300);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

However, when setting the Nimbus L&F, the problem goes away:

[image: JTable Nimbus]

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { }

        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        JTable table = new JTable(12,6);

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setShowGrid(true);
        table.setRowHeight(25);

        dialog.setContentPane(sp);
        dialog.setSize(300,300);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same with the default Windows L&F ?

(Same behavior is observed with java 9 & 10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is how the two look and feels render their grid lines.

The default look and feel `MetalLookAndFeel` (and the `WindowsLookAndFeel`) is based around `BasicLookAndFeel` which uses the `BasicTableUI` class to render the `JTable`.  In [BasicTableUI.paintGrid()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/client/file/c00ce2c36143/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableUI.java#l2027) it calls such as [SwingUtilities2.drawHLine()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/client/file/c00ce2c36143/src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/swing/SwingUtilities2.java#l1078) - which actually calls `Graphics.fillRect()` which is the problem.

The Nimbus look and feel uses the SynthTableUI class.  In [SynthTableUI.paintGrid()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/client/file/c00ce2c36143/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/synth/SynthTableUI.java#l504) it does ultimately call `Graphics.drawLine()`, which clearly draws a cleaner line under scaling.

As you say, that sounds like a bug in the main look and feels under HiDPI.

---

It is possible to create a workaround for this, though it's not particularly elegant.

With a custom version of the `Graphics` that is being used, it's possible to override `fillRect()` to use `drawLine()` instead, if the width or height is 1.  This custom `Graphics` can be introduced specifically when painting the table:

```
    JTable table = new JTable(12, 6) {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(new GraphicsWorkaround(g));
        }
    };
```

(An anonymous subclass is just used for brevity).

Then the `GraphicsWorkaround` class is written as a wrapper to the true `g` that was passed in.  Subclassing `DebugGraphics` here is just a trick to save having to write delegate calls in all the other methods in `Graphics`:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.DebugGraphics;

public class GraphicsWorkaround extends DebugGraphics {
    private final Graphics g;

    public GraphicsWorkaround(Graphics g) {
        super(g);
        this.g = g;
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics create() {
        return new GraphicsWorkaround(g.create());
    }

    @Override
    public void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (width == 1)
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + height - 1);
        else if (height == 1)
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + width - 1, y);
        else
            super.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

(The `create()` method is there to handle the internal `scratchGraphics` clone created in `JComponent.paintComponent()` ).

This then enables `drawLine()` to be called after all, which looked much better at 125% scaling.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer as it clearly explains the underlying cause for this behavior, and propose a good workaround. It however creates a few other issues on my end (when expanding the original example), related to fonts & colors, but I believe I can find solutions for those. I guess I will report the behavior (bug ?) and see what happens.